# Move inline css into a definition

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-selectors

The current view code is shown below.  Technically there is more code because partial views are used where header2 and data2 are listed, but in those partial views the same basic table use is employed.

The problem is that I don't know how to translate the following inline properties into a css definition:

```
width="150px"
valign="top" (I know valign is deprecated - it's only property works there - I don't know why.)
```

The view code:

```
<table class="confSummaryTable">
    <tr>
        <th width="150px">
            header1
        </th>
        <th>
            header2
        </th>
    </tr>
    @For Each item In Model
        @<tr>
            <td valign="top">
                data1
            </td>
            <td>
                data2
            </td>
        </tr>
    Next
```

This is the table definition:

```
confSummaryTable {
    border: none;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

confSummaryTable th, td {
    column-width: 150px;
    vertical-align:text-top;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

This is how the table display appears:

[image]

You can see that the `width` and `valign` properties are applied to the first column because they are explicitly defined inline, but the columns that follow are not picking up the definition I tried to create.  And if I removed the in-line properties for the first column, it reverts to vertical centering and just enough width to display as well.

The following picture shows what the table looks like when inline properties are used in the succeeding partial views.

[image]

How do I write the css table definition so the inline properties will be applied when the view displays?  This is an MVC5 web project using bootstrap css.  The table definition above is in site.css.

Comment: What are those inline properties applied to?

Comment: Why don't you use `width` but `column-width`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your HTML code, this probably should have the same effect as the included inline styles:

```
.confSummaryTable th:first-of-type {
   width: 150px;
}
.confSummaryTable td:first-child {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

But I am not sure what that second CSS rule you added has to do with it..

Added explanation after comment:

`td:first-child` applies only to `td` elements which are the first element inside their container (which is the table row / `tr` in your case) - *every*  `td` that's a first child somewhere inside `.confSummaryTable`. So this fits your HTML.

Concerning `th:first-of-type`: You could actually also use `first-child` here - these two are often interchangeable, but `first-of-type` relates to the tag, type, i.e. the `th`. This would also apply if there were another element inside the first row before the first `th` (which is very unlikely, if not even invalid in tables), in which case it wouldn't be the first child, but still the first of type.

Comment: Perfect.  Is there any comment you can give to explain the concept behind the `first-` terminology being used here?  It seems important.  I saw this during my research, but it didn't seem to be the answer so I failed to try it; that was dumb!  In response to your last comment, the extra lines were attempts I made to achieve the results you gave me.  I do try to research solutions before asking and thought showing what I was trying would indicate I'm not just trying to get everyone to write my code.  I just couldn't figure this one out.  Thx so much.

Comment: I added an explanation to my answer